Is there a language style guide for Mi Yodea?
(I won't be surprised if this question is a dupe)
Recently, one of my posts was edited by another user. One of the edits was to convert a British English spelling of a word into the American English equivalent.
I'm wondering, is American English considered the de facto standard on Mi Yodeya? And does this mean that I should translate British vocabulary into American vocabulary (Trainers/Sneakers, Jumper/Sweater etc. etc.)?

There's no standard of dialect of English (e.g. British or American) on Mi Yodeya.  Thus, generally, edits to switch dialect should not be made.  However, an edit from a dialect-specific word to an equivalent word that's understood universally seems very reasonable, to improve clarity.  Certainly I recommend avoiding terminology that's used by relatively few people (e.g. a word used only in Tyne and Wear or only in New York) or by very few people on the site (e.g. a word used only in India).
By the way, in my experience, edits from one dialect to another are often made not to enforce the latter but because the editor doesn't realize that the usage he's removing is correct.

"but because the editor doesn't realize that the usage he's removing is correct." most often this. It may also because of following spelling & grammar tool which usually can only target 1 language style only.
